# Definir path para salvar arquivos no Linux

Tags: java, tomcat, linux

Tenho um `Back-end` feito em `Java` onde recebo alguns arquivos do front e os salvo em uma pasta. Esse sistema rodava em um servidor `Windows` com `Tomcat` porém recentemente o mesmo teve que ser migrado pra `Debian`.

Antigamente eu definia o path para salvar os arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
D:\\Auditoria\\uploads\\
```

Atualmente o caminho em que quero salvar esses arquivos é:

```
/opt/tomcat/modulos/auditoria/uploads
```

Como mostro na imagem a seguir
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu posso passar esse caminho para salvar meus arquivos? Ou tem outra maneira?

Atualmente crio meu arquivo dessa forma:

```
private final String DIRETORIO_UPLOAD_ARQUIVO = "D:\\Desenvolvimento\\Angular\\Auditoria\\uploads\\anexos\\";
File arquivo= new File(DIRETORIO_UPLOAD_ARQUIVO, file.getFileName());
```

Comment: Desde que o usuário que o tomcat está atrelado (user que starta o serviço) tenha acesso de gravação, não vejo problema!

Comment: Assim à primeira vista é só usar a nova URL.

Comment: Já testaste isso com a nova URL?

Comment: @JorgeB. Estou tentando, tá dando uma exception estou tentando achar os logs para analisar os erros

Comment: Deve estar algures em `/var/log`.

Comment: Como comentado pelo NilsonUehara pode ser uma questão de permissão de escrita.

Comment: Vai no terminal e digite o comando  `#sudo chmod 777 /opt/tomcat/modulos/auditoria/uploads` isso ira liberar permissão de gravação total, não e uma boa pratica fazer isso, mas e um solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DiegoAugusto basta que vc use a URL (path) do diretório destino. É importante apenas ressaltar que o usuário de execução do tomcat (daemon do tomcat) deve ter permissão de execução neste diretório.

Uma forma de fazer isto é colocar o diretório final como propriedade do grupo em que está o usuário do tomcat.

No meu computador (virtualbox) o tomcat é instalado e executado sob o usuário tomcat7 e grupo tomcat7.

Consultar o nome de usuário que está executando o tomcat (faça isto como root)

```
# ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

a resposta será algo do gênero....

```
tomcat7   4001     1  0 11:50 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.....
```

o que mostra que o tomcat está sendo executado pelo usuário tomcat7. É este usuário que deve ter permissão de acesso no diretório que vc quer. Para dar permissão faça (como root):

```
# chown -R tomcat7 /opt/tomcat/modulos/auditoria/uploads
```

Acredito que isto seja suficiente para solucionar o teu problema.

t+